# MySQL Search for duplicate of a one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

I need to find the most efficient way in MySQL to compare 2 different instances of a one to many relationship. Take this table

```
CREATE TABLE `Table` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ParentID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ChildID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `pach` (`ParentID`,`ChildID`),
  KEY `ParentID` (`ParentID`),
  KEY `ChildID` (`ChildID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

insert into `Table` (`ID`,`ParentID`,`ChildID`) values
(1,1,1),
(2,1,2),
(3,1,3),
(4,1,4),
(5,2,1),
(6,2,3),
(7,3,1),
(8,3,3),
(9,3,4),
(10,4,1),
(11,4,4),
(12,4,3);
```

ParentID 3 has an identical set of children to ParentID 4, and that's what i need my query to be able to identify - Given ParentID=4, return ParentID 3 because it has exaclty the same children.

So far the only thing i can come up with is a very ugly group_concat query (see below). What would be a better approach to solve this problem?

```
select distinct(b.ParentID)
from `Table` a, `Table` b where
(select group_concat(ChildID order by ParentID asc) from `Table` where ParentID=a.ParentID )
=
(select group_concat(ChildID order by ParentID asc) from `Table` where ParentID=b.ParentID )
and b.ParentID!=a.ParentID
and a.parentID=4;
+----------+
| ParentID |
+----------+
|        3 |
+----------+
```

Comment: can you post the sql query that you tried?

Comment: @S1LENTWARRIOR yes, i've added it. Thanks for looking

Comment: I don't think your solution is especially ugly, but the outer group by is inappropriate. If you want DISTINCT results, use DISTINCT. (And for the love of humanity, don't call a table `table` under any circumstances. Ever.)

Comment: Hi Again @Strawberry. Thanks for the input, this is part of my long-winded solution the Clique problem i posted about, and that you replied to yesterday.. If i make a workable solution i'll post this up in part answer to that, but i'm not at all confident that it'll be scalable. Anybody else have a better query than the one posted above?

Comment: Well, if it helps, I see this as a subset of the Clique problem; the pantry problem

Comment: Yikes. i've got myself into so many problems these last few days!

Comment: It's a much more manageable problem however

Comment: Then don't leave me hanging @Strawberry, please enlighten me. I've been around in circles on this for days. My group_concat query above won't work because there could be ChildIDs in one ParentID that arent in the other, and theyl intereupt the ordering of the ChildIDs string

Comment: The fact that they interrupt the ordering is evidence that the two sets are different. Therefore they do not have 'exactly the same children'